# What are the cultural roots of the Lamp of the Genie?

Tags: cultural-history, arabia

I'm wondering what the "symbolic etymology", so to speak, is for the Lamp in the story of Aladdin and its relation to the Genie. Why would a genie be bound to an object and be made a servant to its finder? Can one assume the genie did something bad once and was punished to subjugation to the lamp, or is it somehow in their nature? Also, why would it seem reasonable for the genie to be bound to a lamp, of all the things it could be bound to?

Please don't misunderstand: I'm not asking what had happened in the mythological past that caused this particular genie to be bound to this particular lamp, but about what aspects of ancient Arabic culture might give rise to a myth about a genie bound to a lamp; or what the cultural connotations of an oil lamp might be, which would make the thought of someone or something (whichever category a genie would belong to) being bound to it emerge from the Arabic memeplex.

Lastly, I realize that History.SE isn't for mythological questions, but I thought that this question may be okay in that I'm not asking about things within the mythology, but for the historical cultural circumstances that gave rise to it. I'm reasoning that questions about ancient cultural symbols isn't very far removed from questions about ancient languages, which the FAQ explicitly lists as on-topic, or otherwise about historical cultural evolution. If my reasoning is wrong, feel free to close the question, I guess; in that case, perhaps I can at least serve to set a precedent.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question, however Aladdin was only added to the thousand and one nights collection in the 18th century, by a Frenchman, and there are no known prior Arabic sources for the story.

Comment: @YannisRizos: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin) does state that the Frenchman in question did hear the story from a Syrian story-teller.

Comment: Sure, but still there are no Arabic sources documenting the myth (or variations of) before Galland did. If Aladdin was an Arabic myth, it certainly wasn't popular enough.

Comment: Yes; my point was that it seems reasonable (or at least possible) to assume that the story is Arabic in origin, rather than a Western invention merely inspired by a fadaise for the Arabic.

Comment: "The Fisherman and the Jinni" has a genie/jinn bound in a jar. When the jar is opened the genie comes out in a plume of smoke. This is not that different from the tale of the lamp, so I think the concept of a genie bound to a household container has a basis in Arabic myth.

Comment: Great find @called2voyage, and perhaps the start of a good answer.

Comment: I think its a Western invention. Jinn live in the desert, not in lamps or jars.

Comment: @RazieMah: The story of Aladdin aside, I think it's quite uncontroversial that the story of the Fisherman and the Jinni and the myth of Solomon's Ring, as discussed in the answer, are Arabian in origin.

Comment: @Dolda2000 No I disagree. I have never heard that myth about Solomon told that way and there are many versions. IMO it is NOT the myth of Solomons ring what you have posted. Isn't Fisherman and the Jinni from A Thousand and One Arabian Nights?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close since I'm afraid due to the fact that the Bedouin are a nomadic tribe its impossible to know the answer.

Comment: @RazieMah The lore doesn't come from the Bedouin but from medieval Islam. It is not impossible to know the answer.

Comment: @called2voyage I think the Bedouin and other now converted nomadic tribes of Arabia believed in jinn before Islam, but it is hard to know and impossible to know exactly what they believed. There is nowhere near a consensus on the origins of the tales from A thousand and one Arabian Nights, such as the Fisherman and the Jinni. Questions are much better if they don't require so much speculation, because it doesn't match the Q&A format. It's not that question isn't interesting. There are people working on it. Dolda9000 might want to try to check out free PDFs online on the subject

Comment: @RazieMah But believing in jinn in general is not the question. The question is the source of genies being stored in lamps, or more generically household containers.

Comment: Suggest this be moved to the mythology stack exchange; their methodology is probably more useful than historical sources & methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basis for binding genies or *jinn* to household objects comes from medieval Islamic lore surrounding King Solomon of Israel.

> King Solomon used a magic ring to control djinn and protect him from them. The ring was set with a gem, probably a diamond, that had a living force of its own. With the ring, Solomon branded the necks of the djinn as his slaves.
>
> One story tells that a jealous djinn (sometimes identified as Asmodeus) stole the ring while Solomon bathed in the river Jordan. The djinn seated himself on Solomon's throne at his palace and reigned over his kingdom, forcing Solomon to become a wanderer. God compelled the djinn to throw the ring into the sea. Solomon retrieved it and punished the djinn by imprisoning him in a bottle.

<sub>-- [Guiley, Rosemary. *The Encyclopedia of Demons and Demonology*](http://books.google.com/books?id=NHosWhaeWDQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Guiley,%20Rosemary.%20The%20Encyclopedia%20of%20Demons%20and%20Demonology&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G_syU5TUPOm4yAGr3YDAAg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=djinn&f=false)</sub>

The idea that sitting around somewhere on a forgotten shelf was an old, dusty bottle, containing a powerful magical being who was bound to serve human wishes, was an attractive catch for storytellers, as evidenced by the fact that this old legend has been respun several times in tales both ancient and modern.

---

As far as the lamp itself is concerned, it was yet another household container that one might find anywhere. The connection between lamps and spirits was fairly common in Jewish culture (see [Revelation 4:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+4%3A5&version=NIV) for one example), so it is possible the signficance of this imagery played a factor in a lamp being chosen for the tale of Aladdin rather than a bottle or a jar.

Comment: That is very interesting. Might I ask if you can back up the claim that King Solomon's Ring has pre-Islamic roots, however? [Wikipedia seems to claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_Solomon) that it is a strictly Islamic tradition. Not that that being the case makes it a less good answer; I'm just curious.

Comment: @Dolda2000 That was from my source, though the source does seem a little ambiguous as to whether that tale itself was pre-Islamic or jinn in general. I'll see if I can find another source.

Comment: "The Fisherman and the Jinn" is very interesting indeed in this context. I can very much see it being a link between the story of King Solomon's Ring and the story of Aladdin.

Comment: @Dolda2000 You are correct it seems to come from medieval Islamic lore.

Comment: It's surely Bedouin. They were polytheistic and some converted to Judaism and Islam.

Comment: @RazieMah Surely Bedouin? How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: The earliest primary source for King Solomon's Ring comes from The Testament of Solomon. It is believed to be Christian and Greek in origin.

Comment: @RazieMah Islamic lore could have adapted that story without it going through Bedouin. I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: @called2voyage I believe jinn in jars is a Western idea. What you posted here about Solomon is a mix of a first century Christian heresy and the Holy Koran! (which is a literal document) and something about jinn in jars, which doesn't occur in either and that I've never heard before (triple heresy posted as "medieval Islamic folkore!" I would strongly recommend a better source than a dictionary of demonology as a source. The jinn are slaves to Solomon. If he wanted to put them in jars he could and a writer came up with the idea. I think that's all that can be said.

Comment: @RazieMah Heresy can be indigenous to a culture. It doesn't have to be external. "Islamic folklore" is a commonly accepted term for lore that originates within Islamic culture(s) regardless of whether or not it is heretical. Of course, a writer came up with the idea. I make no claims that the idea originated within the Qur'an, any Hadith, or with an Islamic religious leader. In fact, I doubt it did. I'm sure it was a tale spun up by storytellers, but that doesn't mean the story didn't originate within Islamic culture.

Comment: @RazieMah Questioning the veracity of my source is a different matter and should probably be taken to meta. In order to properly break it down, you would have to find what sources were used within The Encyclopedia of Demons and Demonology.

Comment: @called2voyage Muslims literally believe in the jinn. It's not folklore to them.

Comment: @RazieMah I know that, but there is also folklore *surrounding* the jinn. This is not uncommon in many religious cultures. Christians literally believe in angels, but there is also folklore surrounding them.

Comment: @called2voyage There are folklore surrounding the jinn. I agree. Christianity and Islam are different because the Koran is supposed to be the literal word of God, so you can't alter it. This is the issue: "God compelled the djinn to throw the ring into the sea." That's not in the Koran. It's coming from the Testament of Solomon. So it would a heresy to say God did things he didn't do. Heresy is a bit different than folklore.

Comment: @RazieMah Heresy can occur in folklore. That just makes it heretical folklore.

Comment: Ok, I'm going have to end the conversation because its simply not constructive. As I remarked before, there is no consensus answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

Genies (also called jinn or genii) are spirits in cultures of the Middle East and Africa. The term genie comes from the Arabic word jinni, which referred to an evil spirit that could take the shape of an animal or person. It could be found in every kind of nonliving thing, even air and fire.